# parameterized warning silencing macro trouble

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor, token, suppress-warnings

The following [doesn't compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WdX6BbKcmJfXUbRU):

```
#define SUPPRESS(w) _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored " ## w)

SUPPRESS("-Wuseless-cast")

int main() {
    int a = (int)4;
    return a;
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error: pasting ""GCC diagnostic ignored "" and ""-Wuseless-cast"" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Depending on which [phase of translation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) the `_Pragma` directive is handled, you could perhaps rely on the standard consecutive-literal-string concatenation. That means if you have two literal string constants with only whitespace (or comments) between them, then they will be automatically concatenated into a single string. If so then you don't need the preprocessor concatenation operator. You might want to try that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude like ```_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored " w)```?  doesn't work. Also you can experiment with the online compiler link I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that `_Pragma` wants to have an escaped string-literal like so

```
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wuseless-cast\"")
```

So the trick is to add another layer of stringyfication between the call of `SUPPRESS` and the call of `_Pragma` like below

```
#define xSUPPRESS(w) _Pragma(#w)
#define SUPPRESS(w) xSUPPRESS(GCC diagnostic ignored w)

SUPPRESS("-Wuseless-cast")
```

See it [***here***](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jxDvXJhQHz0qHgp1) in action.